# Why Do I Have to Create An Object and Assign It to A Property in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, ios

So I had this code, and it did not work:

```
for (NSDictionary *item in data){
    [self.resultsArray addObject:item];
}
```

self.resultsArray is nil. But then I changed it to this:

```
NSMutableArray *myDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *item in data){
    [myDataArray addObject:item];
}

self.resultsArray = myDataArray;
[myDataArray release];
```

and now it worked. self.resultsArray is now populated

So I'm a beginner in Objective C and I was wondering why can I not just directly use it in the property's addObject. Why did I have to create another mutable array, populate it, assign it to the resultsArray property and release the mutable array I made?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: Also, in a lot of books I've been working on, this is done a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple answer

You didn't initialize `self.resultArray` before adding objects to it. It is just a pointer to the value which is nil until you `alloc` it.

`self.resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` before adding objects to it will solve the issue.

However, this way of alloc'ing will create a memory leak, therefore it is not shown in books and examples. Memory leak can happen if the `self.resultArray` property is marked as `retain` and by calling alloc it will be retained 2 times.

Comment: I get it. Thanks. I have read lots of books and I noticed they always do what I did in the latter part of the code instead of alloc and init-ing the property. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Ygam, i've updated the answer about the memory leak that this creates. please check.

Comment: Er, you should never have to do `self.resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`, because like you said that leaks. See my answer.

Comment: oh and by the way, with iOS 5's ARC, will I need to worry about this?

Comment: @Ygam not sure about this, but you always need to care about mem leaks.

Answer (score 1):

If `self.resultsArray` is nil, then `[self.resultsArray addObject:item]` will **NOT** add an object to the array, it will just do nothing (because the array will be `nil` by default, and sending messages to `nil` is a no-op in Objective-C). When you create a mutable array as a local variable, you can add things to it — then if you assign it to the property, well, everything works as you expect and `self.resultsArray` will no longer be nil.

Typically when you have properties like this, you'd set them up in your init method:

```
- (id)init {
    // ...
        self.resultsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        // or access the ivar directly:
        // _resultsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    // ...
}
```

Then as soon as your object is initialized you'll be able to add things to the array. Again, if you don't do this, it will be `nil` by default, and `[self.resultsArray addObject:item]` will have no effect.

Comment: thanks! and with iOS 5's ARC, will I need to worry about memory leaks in  alloc-ing and init-ing in properties?

Comment: You mean ARC? No, you won't have to worry about it. You can use `alloc`/`init` or just `array`, and the compiler will pick up the difference in retain counts. However you will still need to create this array before you try to use it :)

Comment: @Ygam You can read more about ARC here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you are not initializing the array (I'm going to assume myDataArray is an NSMutableArray).

In your init method, call `myDataArray = [NSMutableArray array];` and it'll work

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to note is that you're not creating ***another*** mutable array as you didn't have an array to start with. Merely declaring a property or variable does not create an object to go along with it. That's why self.resultsArray starts out as *nil*.

The working code you have is designed to allow you to explicitly release the array as you are retaining it twice: once when you alloc it and once when you assign it to your property. You only want one of those retains, so you release once.

You could just do:

```
self.resultsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self.resultsArray release];


for (NSDictionary *item in data){
    [self.resultsArray addObject:item];
}
```

This is less code, but it's not as clear. Clarity is important.